# How to add google map on WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I have been working in this code, and works fine in localhost, but when I try to put this in word press the map doesn't come, and I don't know how to fix case I am new in WordPress.

A really need a hand on this, thanks

```js
var geocoder;
function initMap() {
    GeolocateUser();
    var enderesso, Dest_location;
    var UserLocation;
    var markers = [];
    var origin_place_id = null;
    var destination_place_id = null;
    var travel_mode = google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING;
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    mapTypeControl: false,
    zoom: 13
    });
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    draggable: true,
    map: map,
    });
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    var origin_input = document.getElementById('origin-input');
    var destination_input = document.getElementById('destination-input');
    var total_distance = document.getElementById('total-distance');
    var total_duration = document.getElementById('total-duration');

    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(origin_input);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(destination_input);

    var origin_autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(origin_input);
    origin_autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
    var destination_autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(destination_input);
    destination_autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

// On Change route action
  directionsDisplay.addListener('directions_changed', function(){
    total_distance.value = getDistance(directionsDisplay.getDirections());
    total_duration.value = getDuration(directionsDisplay.getDirections());
  });

// On click map action
  map.addListener('click',function(e){
    clearMarkers();
    if (!UserLocation) {
        UserLocation=e.latLng;
        addMarker(e.latLng);
        route();
    }else{
        Dest_location=e.latLng;
        route();
    }

  });

  origin_autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    var place = origin_autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
      return;
    }
    clearMarkers();
    expandViewportToFitPlace(map, place);

    // If the place has a geometry, store its place ID and route if we have
    // the other place ID
    origin_place_id = place.place_id;
    UserLocation = place.geometry.location;
    addMarker(UserLocation);
    route();
  });

  destination_autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    var place = destination_autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
      return;
    }
    expandViewportToFitPlace(map, place);
    clearMarkers();
    // If the place has a geometry, store its place ID and route if we have
    // the other place ID
    Dest_location = place.geometry.location;
    destination_place_id = place.place_id;
    route();
  });

  function route() {
    if (!UserLocation || !Dest_location) {
      return;
    }
    clearMarkers();
    directionsService.route({
      origin: UserLocation ,
      destination: Dest_location,
      travelMode: travel_mode
    }, function(response, status) {
      if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });
  }
    // Adds a marker to the map and push to the array.
    function addMarker(location) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:location,
            map: map
        });
        markers.push(marker);
    }

    // Sets the map on all markers in the array.
    function setMapOnAll(map) {
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(map);
      }
    }

    // Removes the markers from the map, but keeps them in the array.
    function clearMarkers() {
      setMapOnAll(null);
    }

    // Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them.
    function deleteMarkers() {
      clearMarkers();
      markers = [];
    }
    //Get Distance
    function getDistance(result){
        var d = 0;
        var myroute = result.routes[0];
        for (var i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
            d += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
        }
        d=(d/1000);
        return d;
    }

    //Get duration
    function getDuration(result){
        var time = 0;
        var myroute = result.routes[0];
        for (var i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
            time += myroute.legs[i].duration.value;
        }
        time =(time/60)+10;
        time = time.toFixed(0);
        return time;
    }

    //Get full adress
    function getAddress(latLng) {
        var edress;
        geocoder.geocode( {'latLng': latLng},
          function(results, status) {
            if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              if(results[0]) {
                adress = results[0].formatted_address;
              }
              else {
                adress = "No results";
              }
            }
            else {
            adress = status;
            }
        });
        return adress;
    }

    //Geolocate User
    function GeolocateUser(){
        UserLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(0.0,0.0);
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
              UserLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude+0, position.coords.longitude+0);
              addMarker(UserLocation);
              map.setCenter(UserLocation);
          });
        }
    }

    //View Point Simple
    function expandViewportToFitPlace(map, place) {
        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
          map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
          map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
          map.setZoom(11);
    }

  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #map {
            height: 100%;
        }
        .controls {
            margin-top: 10px;
            border: 1px solid transparent;
            border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            height: 32px;
            outline: none;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        }

        #origin-input,
        #destination-input {
            background-color: #fff;
            font-family: Roboto;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: 300;
            margin-left: 12px;
            padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            width: 200px;
        }

        #origin-input:focus,
        #destination-input:focus {
            border-color: #4d90fe;
        }

        #mode-selector {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #4d90fe;
            margin-left: 12px;
            padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
        }

        #mode-selector label {
            font-family: Roboto;
            font-size: 13px;
            font-weight: 300;
        }

    </style>
    <input id="origin-input" class="controls" type="text"
        placeholder="Enter an origin location">

    <input id="destination-input" class="controls" type="text"
        >
    <input type="text" id="total-distance" placeholder="Calculating.."/>
    <input type="text" id="total-duration" placeholder="Calculating.."/>

    <div id="map"></div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have any error in your console?

Comment: Did you set your credentials for this api to allow your site url to use the map? if not, thats why. Nothing to do with WP.

Comment: the console is clear, no errors all its working fine on localhost but  how i put this in wp post

Comment: rgdesign do you are talking about the key, its it ?